# How to read data from datagrid in specific date range using java and selenium webdriver

Tags: java, excel, datagrid, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

**Scenario :** for example want to fetch **Column name: Owner Name | Shared Held | Date** from data grid of **website: nasdaq.com/symbol/ctsh/institutional-holdings** In date range say 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014 or 01/01/2013to 31/12/2013 and want put it into excel sheet. please guide me on this.

==============

**Code** I designed this code to read data from data grid and all pages now am looking for solution for above mention Scenario.

```
 public class NasdaqReadTabaleData {

    // extends Nasdaqe_InvesterListData{
public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Test
public void NasdaqeTable() throws Exception {

    driver.get("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol"); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   /* for (int i = 1; i < s.getRows(); i++)
    {
    //Read data from excel sheet
    String s1 = s.getCell(0,i).getContents();*/
    driver.findElement(By.id("stock-search-text")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("stock-search-text")).sendKeys("CTSH");
    driver.findElement(By.id("stock-search-submit")).click();

    JavascriptExecutor jsedown = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jsedown.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");

    //Click on holdings link.
    driver.findElement(By.id("holdingslink")).click();
    System.out.println("Action should counduct once  ");
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    try
    {
        JavascriptExecutor jsedownsmall = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jsedownsmall.executeScript("scroll(0, 950)");

        WebElement Webtable =driver.findElement(By.id("secfilingContainer")); 
        if(Webtable.isDisplayed()){

            // Replace TableID with Actual Table ID or Xpath
        List<WebElement> TotalRowCount=Webtable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount.size());

        // Now we will Iterate the Table and print the Values   
            int RowIndex=1;
            for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
            {
                  List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td[3]"));
                  int ColumnIndex=1;
                  for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
                  {
                       System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
                       ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;

                   }
                  RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
            } 

            // Paging functionality For All Paages 

        // locator for last page button         
        List<WebElement> lastPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[9]/form/div[15]/div/ul/ul/li"));
        System.out.println("Paging functionality");

        for(int i=1; i<=(lastPage.size()); i++)
            {
            if (lastPage.size()>=0){
                //locator for next page button
                List<WebElement> nextPage = driver.findElements(By.id("quotes_content_left_lb_NextPage"));
                if(nextPage.size() >= 1){
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    nextPage.get(0).click();

                    JavascriptExecutor jsedownsmall1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    jsedownsmall1.executeScript("scroll(0, 950)");

                    WebElement Webtable1 =driver.findElement(By.id("secfilingContainer")); 

                    if(Webtable1.isDisplayed()){
                        List<WebElement> TotalRowCount1=Webtable1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

                            System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount1.size());

                            // Now we will Iterate the Table and print the Values   
                            int RowIndex1=1;
                            for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount1)
                            {
                                List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td[3]"));
                                int ColumnIndex=1;
                                for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
                                {
                                    //System.out.println("Current Page ::"+lastPage);
                                    System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex1+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
                                    ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;

                                    WebElement excelData[][] = new WebElement[1][10];
                                    excelData[0][0] = colElement;

                                }
                                RowIndex1=RowIndex1+1;
                            } 
                    }
                }else lastPage.get(0).click();
            }
            }
        }
        }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will not get full ready made code here , did you try by yourself? then please share your code with question and you will get help to correct that code according to your need.

Comment: Hi I added my code , please help me to achieve my scenario

Comment: Okay , now tell please that what error you are getting in that code?

Answer (score 0):

am trying below mention code to read data in date rang , but i think it is not proper .

@Test
     public void print_data() throws Exception{
         String startDate = "01/01/2014";
         String endDate = "09/30/2014";

```
String final_xpath = first_part+k+forth_part;
String Table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getText(); (Hear am reading three column Owner Name | Shared Held | Date )
```

if(Table_data.contains(startDate)||Table_data.contains(endDate)){ (Want to write logic pick data in date range 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014)

```
System.out.print(Table_data1 +"  ");// to print on console
excelLog(i,Table_data2,Table_data3,Table_data4); // To print in excel sheet
```